# Pass list to function, add value and print

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to pass an empty list, add a value to it and then print the value:

```
let add_to_list (my_list : string list) = 
  my_list@["somevalue"]; print_list(my_list)

let print_list lst = 
  print_string(string_of_list(lst) (fun a -> a) ",")

add_to_list [];
```

Nothing shows in the list. But when I call it with `add_to_list ["a"; "b"]` those and only those values show. Man OCaml is really hard

Comment: when you do `my_list@["..."]; print_list(my_list)` then `my_list` is not really changed (indeed you can just as well ignore the first step) ... you cannot mutate the list ;) ... so do `print_list(my_list@[".."])` instead ;)

Comment: you don't need the type annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` operator concatenates two lists and returns the result as a new list -- it does not affect the inputs.

You need to capture the result in a new binding, and print that instead:

```
let add_to_list (my_list : string list) = 
  let new_list = my_list @ ["somevalue"] in
  print_list(new_list)
```

Comment: awesome! it's the same with the :: operator?

Comment: yes: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/a-guided-tour.html#constructing-lists-with